# How can I eliminate multiple devices (virtual HDD), and use my original one from my first installation?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, virtualbox, python

I am running Ubuntu on VirtualBox 5.2 on a Windows 10 system.  I first ran Ubuntu in an older version of VirtualBox 3 years ago.  I upgraded my VirtualBox and Ubuntu, and was unable to see my original data.  I went back to the original iso with the new VirtualBox and I can see my data.  I then allowed the new VirtualBox to attempt an Ubuntu install twice.  I now have 3 volumes (devices...or virtual hard drives) that are visible in my sidebar.  The oldest of them is my original one, but the newest one is now my main one.  The others got relocated under a different directory tree under /media/...  I cannot run my python files from there as all the Python files are located there, and the terminal does not look there for them.  I would like to return the original drive to the main and eliminate the others.  It is the one with Python3 installed and all of my work.  I don't know if I can undo installations or relocated the devices.  elimination should be easy once the relocation is accomplished.

Comment: What do you mean you went back to the original ISO, do you mean the virtual HDD, if you do then you should clarify what you mean.

Comment: The ISO is the Ubuntu image file that is used to boot the system.  The virtual hard drives are something else that are visible once the system is booted, but not before.  The reference to going back to the original iso is because the Ubuntu16 did not have my old HDD visible, and when I put the Ubuntu14 iso back in as the main iso, my old HDD is visible but it is not my main device, so it is not root, and my terminal does not access it or its files.

Comment: If accessing the files is the objective, I've successfully used 7Zip to mount LINUX and Windows virtual hard drives to extract / rescue files when my circumstances didn't accommodate using a Virtual PC/Hypervisor like VBox and Virtual PC.

Comment: I was able to extract the files, as they are all on a USB drive now.  I just want to run them again.